# How to add a new collator key to a my parachain in a development setup?

Tags: collator

I have a relay chain running with two validators. I wanted to connect a parachain with one collator node. I want to use my own key for the collator instead of using the predefined keys like `//Alice` etc.

Can anyone please point me to a guide to achieve this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a new collator key to your Polkadot parachain in a development setup, you can follow these steps:

Generate a new key pair for the collator using a tool such as subkey or polkadot-js.

Add the new key to your local node's keystore by running the following command:

```sh
polkadot-js keyring add <key-name> --type sr25519 --suri <path-to-my-key>
```

Replace `<key-name>` with the name you want to give to your new key and `<path-to-my-key>` with the path to the file containing your key.

Update your node's configuration file to include the new collator key. The configuration file is usually located in the `./config` directory and is named chain_spec.rs. You will need to update the genesis section and add the new key to the validators array:

```json
"genesis": {
    ...
    "validatorIds": [
        "<existing-validator-1>",
        "<existing-validator-2>",
        "<new-collator-key>"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Replace `<existing-validator-1>` and `<existing-validator-2>`

with the existing validator keys that you want to retain, and replace `<new-collator-key>` with the new key you just generated.

Restart your node to apply the changes.

Once you have completed these steps, your node should be able to function as a collator using the new key you added.

edit1: Have you gone through these steps?

Generate a new keypair for the collator node using the subkey command-line tool.

```sh
subkey generate --scheme sr25519
```

Add the generated key to the aura section of the collator's chain specification file.

```json
"aura": {
  "authorities": ["your_generated_key"],
  "params": {
    "stepDuration": 6,
    "validators": 1
  }
}
```

Launch the collator node with the new key using the `--validator` and `--key` flags.

```sh
./collator_binary --validator --key "your_generated_key_seed"
```

Update the relay chain's chain specification file to include the parachain with the collator's node endpoint and ID.

```json
"parachains": {
  "2001": {
    "bin": "path/to/parachain/binary",
    "id": 2001,
    "paraGenesis": "path/to/para/genesis",
    "collatorEndpoint": "/ip4/<collator_node_ip>/tcp/<collator_node_port>"
  }
}
```

Finally, start the relay chain and connect it with the parachain by referencing its ID.

```sh
./relaychain_binary --parachain-id 2001
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Kayvan for the quick response.

I am following exactly the same procedure to register my collator with the relay chain but my parachain is not producing any blocks. 

When I connect the parachain with the relay chain with the custom collator at work (Alice, bob) it produces blocks but when I generate my own account keys and use these keys as collator, the parachain stop producing blocks. 

I am using following command to generate my keys:

./target/release/my-node key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive

Comment: Thank you very much!

It worked. Now the parachain is producing blocks.